# Zurückschicken vs. Zurückzuschicken

Tags: infinitive

Folgendes ist mir gerade unklar.

"blablablabla. Daher brauchen Sie meine Unterlagen zunächst nicht zurückschicken."

"blablablabla. Daher brauchen Sie meine Unterlagen zunüchst nicht zurück**zu**schicken."

Was ist hier richtig? Oder ist Beides korrekt?

Nach dem Link, gilt immer brauchen mit "zu". Grundsätzlich seh ich aber kaum einen Unterschied zwischen

"Du brauchst A nicht tun."

"Du musst A nicht tun."

Nach der Regel müsste Ersteres aber heißen

"Du brauchst A nicht **zu** tun."

Ich versteh den Sinn nicht so ganz dahinter. Es gibt Fälle, wo ein "zu" Pflicht ist, weil der Satz sonst komisch klingt, wie z.B. in diesem Satz

"Ich möchte Sie höflichst bitten, Ihre Entschuldigung zurück**zu**nehmen."

(Muss nach bitten ein Komma?). Das sagt mir aber mein Sprachgefühl; begründen kann ich das nicht.

Darüber hinaus, ist es möglich "zurückzuschicken" auseinander zu schreiben? Also "zurück zu schicken"? Ist das optional?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135178/discussion-on-question-by-diger-zuruckschicken-vs-zuruckzuschicken).

Comment: Ah, OK. Ich kann die Seite noch sehen, aber das liegt wohl daran, dass ich Mod bin. Was willst du denn wissen? Bedenke bitte, dass Kommentare generell als flüchtig konzipiert sind - sie sind nicht dafür gedacht, und können im Grunde jederzeit gelöscht werden.

Comment: Du hattest glaub ich Seiten verlinkt die nochmal erklären wann etwas zusammengeschrieben wird und wann nicht "zu". Außerdem waren da die expliziten Beispiele, die ich nachgefragt habe, die ich gerne als Referenz nehme ;)

Comment: Die Frage - ob "Du brauchst A nicht tun" richtig ist, wird doch hier schon beantwortet, oder? german.stackexchange.com/questions/38621/brauchen-infinitv zu 2) Ja, das könnte hier theoretisch kurz im Kommentar beantwortet werden. Die Philosophie der Seite ist aber, nicht nur dir zu helfen, sondern eine Wissenssammlung bereitszustellen. Der dahinterstehende Gedanke ist, dass später Leute mit der gleichen Frage die Antwort hier leicht finden können. Deswegen sollte jede Frage in eine Frage gepackt werden, und nicht mal ebenso nebenbei in einem Kommentar abgefrühstückt werden.

Comment: zurückzuschicken muss zusammen geschrieben werden. Das Stichwort hier ist, dass zurückschicken ein trennbares Verb ist. mein-deutschbuch.de/infinitivsaetze.html bringt es auf den Punkt: Handelt es sich um ein trennbares Verb, so steht " zu " zwischen Verbzusatz (Vorsilbe) und dem Verb. Der Infinitiv der trennbaren Verben wird demnach zusammengeschrieben. Das Komma in "Ich möchte Sie bitten, ..." is optional. Die Regeln findest du hier texterclub.de/… Dein Fall ist der letzte dort genannte.